How can I change the output method based on if a function was called by a short code or action hook
I have a function that is hooked to the end all posts. I'm adding a shortcode so the same function can be called else where. And I need to change the output method based on whether the function was called by a shortcode or the hook.
I have this:
if (did_action('hd_related_posts') > 0) {
    // Function was called by the 'hd_related_posts_shortcode' shortcode
    return ob_get_clean();
} else {
    echo" Function was not called by the shortcode";
      echo ob_get_clean();
}


But even when I call the function from the shortcode, this IF statement returns false and the output is echoed when it should be returned. How do I fix this?

Not sure how you hooked it "to the end of all posts", whether that passes any parameters that inside the function would allow you to differentiate between these two scenarios. But it would probably be easier, if you modified how you are hooking this to the end of all posts - so that you do not call the function directly there, but use do_shortcode. Then your function itself doesn't need to be able to make this distinction any more.

To do as you suggest would require editing the theme template. Not a great idea.

Why would it require that? Just change what the function you hooked into the footer does - and have it call do_shortcode.
